# Best way to implement dynamic data model in ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-core-5.0

I have: **Ef Core 5**, **Postgresql**, and **models**:

```
public class Workitem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

```
public struct Field
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public FieldValueType ValueType { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
        => ReferenceEquals(this, obj) || obj is Field other && this.Value == other.Value;

    public override int GetHashCode()
        => Value.GetHashCode();
}
```

```
public enum FieldValueType
{
    ValueAsString,
    ValueAsDate,
    ValueAsDatetime,
    ValueAsInt,
    ValueAsDouble,
    ValueAsBool,
    ValueAsDictionary
}
```

I want to implement the ability to store a dynamic set of Fields in Workitem, while each Field can have a different type of Value.
I need a solution that will be convenient to work with both on the client side (application) and on the database server side (when translating to SQL).

```
db.Workitems.Where(wi => wi.Fields.Any(f => 
       (f.ValueType == FieldValueType.ValueAsInt && f.Value >= 2)
    || (f.ValueType == FieldValueType.ValueAsString == "abc"))
    .ToList();
```

or

```
new List<Workitem>(){ new Workitem() { Fields = new List<Fields>() { new Field() { ValueType = FieldValueType.ValueAsInt, Value = 1 } } } }
.Where(wi => wi.Fields.Any(f => 
       (f.ValueType == FieldValueType.ValueAsInt && f.Value >= 2)
    || (f.ValueType == FieldValueType.ValueAsString == "abc"))
    .ToList();
```

or

```
db.Workitem.Add(new Workitem() { Fields = new List<Fields>() { new Field() { ValueType = FieldValueType.ValueAsDatetime, Value = DateTimeOffset.Now } } });
```

This should work correctly with IQueryable and IEnumerable

I have found several solutions but could not find one that is convenient in any of them.
Previously, this was implemented using **EAV**, now everything tends to the **JSONB** columns of postgresql, since npgsql can work with them.

I added this configuration, but when deserializing I have specified the type of the "Value" field as "Object", I am experiencing difficulties with deserializing.

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Workitem> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    builder.Property(x => x.Caption).HasMaxLength(150);
    builder.Property(x => x.Fields)
        .HasColumnType("jsonb")
        .HasConversion(
            v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
            v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Field>>(v),
            new ValueComparer<List<Field>>(
                (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
                c => c.ToList()));
}
```

I also saw implementations with a separate field for each data type, but this is a bad option.

```
public struct Field
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public FieldValueType ValueType { get; set; }

    public string _strValue;
    public int? _intValue;
    public double? _doubleValue;
    ...

    public dynamic Value //return _<type>Value
}
```

I want to get a solution that is as convenient and as simple as possible.

Comment: Maybe it is worth looking in something like [table per hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) and introducing an descendant for `Field`(and making it as a class) per field type?

Comment: @garkushin did you find a solution? I am looking for the exact same pattern.